# How to float the html elements in small blocks and when one block is expand, others should align properly?

Tags: html, css

I have created a list of divs with 50px height and 50px width which are floated in main div.

But when I expand only one div to 100px height, div below will move to the next place with an empty space before the expanded div.

Comment: use `flexbox` property.

Answer (score 0):

Use **flexbox** property, find the sample related code below

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

section:nth-child(2) { height: calc(100px + 20px); /* double height + margin */ }
section:nth-child(8) { height: calc(100px + 20px); /* double height + margin */ }
section:nth-child(13) { height: calc(100px + 20px); /* double height + margin */ }


section:nth-child(1)  { order: 1; }
section:nth-child(2)  { order: 5; }
section:nth-child(3)  { order: 9; }
section:nth-child(4)  { order: 13; }
section:nth-child(5)  { order: 15; }
section:nth-child(6)  { order: 18; }
section:nth-child(7)  { order: 2; }
section:nth-child(8)  { order: 13; }
section:nth-child(9)  { order: 14; }
section:nth-child(10) { order: 16; }
section:nth-child(11) { order: 3; }
section:nth-child(12) { order: 7; }
section:nth-child(13) { order: 11; }
section:nth-child(14) { order: 15; }
section:nth-child(15) { order: 19; }
section:nth-child(16) { order: 4; }
section:nth-child(17) { order: 8; }
section:nth-child(18) { order: 12; }
section:nth-child(19) { order: 16; }
section:nth-child(20) { order: 20; }


/* decorative styles */
#container {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: lightyellow;
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
}

.box {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    
    /* center align numbers */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<article id="container">
    <section class="box">1</section>
    <section class="box">2</section>
    <section class="box">3</section>
    <section class="box">4</section>
    <section class="box">5</section>
    <section class="box">6</section>
    <section class="box">7</section>
    <section class="box">8</section>
    <section class="box">9</section>
    <section class="box">10</section>
    <section class="box">11</section>
    <section class="box">12</section>
    <section class="box">13</section>
    <section class="box">14</section>
    <section class="box">15</section>
    <section class="box">16</section>
    <section class="box">17</section>
    <section class="box">18</section>
    <section class="box">19</section>
    <section class="box">20</section>
</div>
```